# Compiling error in Google Play in-app billing demo TrivialDrive

Tags: android, google-play

Sorry about my poor English. I'm not living in an English-speaking country.
I download google's in-app billing demo and tried to compile and run that. but I found that there is an error in res/values-v 11 and v 14.
and eclipse tells me that "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Halo.Light'"

Anybody see this before?

Comment: what is Android build target of our project ? it should be `android 4.0`

Comment: There is no error in the res folder anymore, but another problem appears in IabHelper.startSetup.onServiceDisconnected function:Multiple markers at this line
 - The method onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName) of type new ServiceConnection(){} 
  must override a superclass method
 - implements android.content.ServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected

Answer (score 1):

Set the Java version to 1.6 for the project. Right click project, select 'Properties', then go to 'Java Compiler', click 'Enable project specific settings' and select 1.6 for JDK compliance. Of course you need to be using a 1.6 JDK with Eclipse for this to work.